# Better way in SQL Server 2012 to parse fixed width string?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am working with data from an older system that has a generic "transaction" table with a data column that contains various record types, and where the decimal is not included.

For example the following row has a price  of 358.25 a premium of 0 (00.00) and a tonnes amount of 003.382, so the correct gross value is 1104.1265

```
358250000003082-
```

My T-SQL to extract this is (ignore the substring values the actual data column is much bigger than my example)

```
convert(decimal(6,0), SUBSTRING(data,105,6))/1000 * (convert(decimal(5,0), SUBSTRING(data,51,5))/100 + convert(decimal(4,0), SUBSTRING(data,56,4)/100)) grossPrice
```

This works well enough but I need to do it in lots of places and if I get a bracket in the wrong place it runs fine but gives the wrong result.

Is there a better way to convert a string to a decimal where the number of decimal places is implied?

I was hoping for something like `convert(decimal(6,3), '003082')` but this generates an overflow error (understandably)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your example easily enough. You just have to take into account the integer math. You will notice I divided by 1000. That causes an implicit conversion so you get the proper decimal places.

```
select cast(convert(int, '003082') / 1000. as numeric(6,3))
```